# APSW tag significance

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I do not see any significance to the [apsw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apsw) tag apart from product promotion. It appears that this tag was created by the developer, and over the years it has been assigned to 13 questions only. Even searching for **"[sqlite] apsw"** yields 129 question as of this writing. A search for **"apsw"** alone yields just 184 questions, and it appears at first glance that they are somehow related to the same software. APSW may or may not be noteworthy (I am aware of it but never got to try it), but clearly there are not that many dedicated questions, and most of the askers do not check for/use this tag anyway.

For the reason above, using this tag as a filter is pretty much pointless and may be considered harmful in a sense that it filters out most of the potentially relevant questions, so I would question the justification for its continual existence.

Comment: [APSW](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) = *Another Python [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) Wrapper*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> may be considered harmful in a sense that it filters out most of the potentially relevant questions

That is not "harmful". That is the tag currently being underused. If it were to really be considered, then we should not have any tags at all. Because if that were the case any tag would be "harmful" for not being used enough, thus removed before it is used enough. And that is not how tags work.

The tag is on-topic as it concerns a particular technology. The usage statistics of the tag are not a criteria when considering whether it should be removed.

The tag does add information to a post, it is not ambiguous. It seems completely unfit for removal. In fact, it only seems like you do not like it because it is "product promotion" and then decided to fabricate a different justification, as "it is not used much, thus harmful" rings very hollow.

Tags describe technologies. That is what they do. It is hardly a "promotion" to have a tag for one particular library, considering most tags describe some technology belonging to somebody. From programming languages, to libraries, frameworks, even actual paid products. Which the APSW library is not.

---

> Even searching for "[sqlite] apsw" yields 129 question as of this writing.

That query does not give you *questions* but questions *and answers*. The query `[sqlite] apsw is:q` shows 46 results. Which makes it far less of a menace than what the proposal tries to portray.

> A search for "apsw" alone yields just 184 questions

And `apsw is:q` yields 80 results.

> but clearly there are not that many dedicated questions, and most of the askers do not check for/use this tag anyway.

The tag was created 2017-03-29. So, checking for all questions which *mention* "apsw" but are not tagged [apsw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apsw) and are posted after that date using the query `apsw is:q -[apsw] created:2017-03-29..` shows 14 results. Which paints a rather different picture than this often neglected tag, present on barely even 7% of the questions it belongs, which the proposal tried to argue.
It is missing on (at most) 14 questions posted after it was created. And it probably needs to be added to older questions, that is true, but it is hardly an argument *against* the tag that it is not present on those.

---

I went through [all questions that *mention* "aspw" but did not have the tag [apsw]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apsw+is%3Aq+-%5Bapsw%5D) (search term `apsw is:q -[apsw]`) and added the tag where it seemed to be necessary. A decent amount of questions mention it without actually being a question *about* that library. For example, it seems to crop up in error messages frequently.

After I finished, there are now

- `apsw is:q -[apsw]` has 42 questions. [Link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apsw+is%3Aq+-%5Bapsw%5D)
- `apsw is:q [apsw]` has 37 questions. [Link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apsw+is%3Aq+%5Bapsw%5D)

I invite anybody interested to verify if the tagging is correct.

Comment: While I do not agree with all points, I do not want to continue arguing on "secondary" matters. This answer does bring important SO usage points, highlighting the lack of a proper advanced and detailed SO usage guide. And no, Q&A/FAQs format is not a good replacement for a proper structured guide (IMHO, documenting SO in the SO format is kind of a poor man's docs). Documentation is a separate matter, though.

Answer (score 8):

While it might be insignificant it still doesn't check any of the boxes in the preliminary check imo.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

And since

> A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination. In any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm

This is not a case for burnination.

Comment: Well, because "In any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm," I specifically explained why I consider it potentially harmful. And this list of potential problems is not all-inclusive and should NOT be considered as a requirement.

Comment: TBF I think this request is a ["complete and utter waste of everyone's time"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) it's not harmful if a tag limits the search, it's their intended purpose. If anything maybe it should be applied to those 129 questions.

Comment: Whether the tag should be applied to the other questions is a question of its own. No, the tag's purpose IS NOT to limit the search. The tag's purpose is to limit the search in a way that helps access relevant questions! Here, you should NOT use this tag for search, because most of the potentially relevant questions are left out, and plain text search provides a much more useful result. The latter also means that the tag does NOT add any meaningful information to the post.